# Homebox column number different on mobile?

Tags: theming, dashboard

I have created a 3 column [homebox](https://drupal.org/project/homebox) site with rss feeds in an attempt to roll my own replacement for google ig (which is to shut soon). It works perfectly for what I want. Is there a simple method to serve up a 1 column version of the same site to mobile users? I have been investigating browscap and adaptive theme (AT) but I was hoping there was a simple method of serving the same site with 1 column instead of three (must use homebox)?

Desktop:
[image: screenshot of desktop version]
Mobile:
[image: mobile]

Comment: This will be done using css3 media queries. CSS is beyond the scope of this site as it isn't Drupal specific. Your going to target the containers and resize them using something like @media screen and (max-width:740px{.section{width:100%;clear:both;}}. Sorry comments to not allow formatting and I am not going to post this as an answer as your question will most likely be closed as being off-topic.

Comment: I thought that because this was a homebox and adaptive theme question, it'd be right at home here.

Comment: Unfortunately while its related it isn't drupal specific. Some CSS questions sometimes make it through though either way I gave you an answer to use.

Comment: I am a drupal and css newbie I'm afraid, so I was hoping for a simple answer. I will investigate AT (and css) some more then?

Comment: I have added an answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50722/switch-to-drupal-mobile-theme-programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your css.

```
@media screen and (max-width:740px){
    .homebox-column-wrapper{
          width:100%!important;
          clear:both;
    }
}
```

Comment: See edit. This code didn't do what I wanted. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: There is something in the AT theme that is doing that because it works just fine in Omega sub theme. Without access to the site I'm afraid this as far as I can take you.  Maybe there is a height value set somewhere that needs to be overridden. Can't say for sure without direct access.

Comment: Ok Nigel. I'll give it a try. Just to clarify though: In Omega theme the homebox will go to 1 column? Thanks.

Comment: I am not suggesting switching to omega. I am suggesting to check on a height value that is being applied. Use firebug to inspect it. Other than that I cannot do much more without being able to directly inspect the code myself. It could be a 100 different things.

Comment: That doesn't quite answer me. I am a little sceptical that homebox is going to change the number of columns it displays based on a width or height value. As I said  I am a drupal newbie. You say it works fine. Are you using homebox also?

Comment: This is how media queries works.  You need to understand CSS to be able to do this. Providing you with snippets of CSS is just taking shots in the dark. There are many ways to solve this issue and unfortunately without access to your site I cannot gove you a definitive one. And yes, I am using home box.

Comment: Okay. Well that's interesting to hear. This is a personal site on my LAN, replacing my google ig page. The mobile aspect is rather minor. It's just a problem I'm trying to solve for my own personal satisfaction. If you've got it working, maybe i'll persevere with attempting to resolve the issue.

Comment: Sorry. I wish I could help, but I would need to inspect the css to see what is impeding it and play with it. Screenshots really don't help and i need to see the AT css and the id/classes of the divs.

Comment: Changed  `width:100% !important;` and now it works. It was very easy.

Comment: lol. I had !important in my example code initially in my answer but I took it out on a revision because it may have been unnecessary. I guess not. I am glad it worked.